# Tabulator - Selectable with selection Eligibility on another column (boolean) which is also a tickCross editable

Tags: tabulator

I have a table with selectable rows using the selection eligibility based on another column (boolean), this eligibility column is editable (tickcross). This is set up in such a way that if this column value is 'true' then the row is selectable, which works just fine when the data is loaded in tabulator. But when click on to toggle the tickcross, the column value toggles but then the row does reflect the selectability  for which the selection eligibility has changed accordingly. 
How can I make sure that after the column value changes the row is either selectable/not-selectable automatically? or is there a workaround for this which I can use? I tried calling the redraw method in my method which toggles the tickcross soon after changing the tickcross column value, but that did not work.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the ***selectableCheck*** function is called when the row is first rendered as it affects styling.

At the moment there is no built in way round this, but you could turn off row selection

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    selectable:false,
});
```

and then use the ***rowClick*** callback to the toggle row selection if it meets the criteria:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowClick:function(e, row){
    //e - the click event object
    //row - row component

        if(row.getData().selectField){ //check for whichever field allows selection
            row.toggleSelect(); //toggle selected state
        }
    },
});
```

In version 4.1, released in a couple of weeks, there will be the ability to regenerate the row, so the selection check will be carried out again.

Comment: Works for me, Thank you :)